# How to handle two actions related to order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 3.1 . This is a typical e-commerce application.

I have two step process:

Step1 : collect shipping and billing address.
Step2: collect shipping method (ground shipping, air shipping, next day delivery etc).

An order has one shipping address, one billing address and one shipping method.

I using the standard REST and used up the edit method of orders_controller to handle step1.

To handle I wanted to use

```
<%= form_for(@current_order) do |f| %>
```

but that will take me to orders_controller. I created a new controller called shipping_methods controller to handle step2.

What is the best approach to handle such situations.

Here is my routes file

```
  resources :orders,    only: [:edit, :update] do
    resource :shipping_method
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you actually post the form before the shipping data is entered, you'll have to find some way to keep all the info entered until the user finishes the shipping part...

it may lead to having some "stale" orders in your system (users filling only the first part and quitting). i suggest doing something like a wizard (there are countless examples on Google on how to do that) using javascript.